# tensorboard not found when install offline

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed tensorboard 1.9.0 by `sudo -H pip install tensorboard-1.9.0-py2-none-any.whl`

and use `pip list` can see it:

```
>> pip list| grep tensorboard
tensorboard       1.9.0
```

but when I try to install tensorflow

`sudo -H pip install tensorflow-1.8.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

it turns to collecting tensorboard:

```
Collecting tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0 (from tensorflow==1.8.0)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0 (from tensorflow==1.8.0) (from versions: 1.0.0a3, 
1.0.0a4, 1.0.0a5, 1.0.0a6)
No matching distribution found for tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0 (from 
tensorflow==1.8.0)
```

I wonder why this happens and how could I install tensorflow offline?

Answer (score 2):

You installed the wrong version of `tensorboard`. You installed version `1.9.0`. But when installing `tensorflow` it is looking for `tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0` which is not satisfied by `1.9.0`.

Download and install [tensorboard 1.8](https://pypi.org/project/tensorboard/1.8.0/#files) and it should work